# Points in multiple polygons

Tags: r, point-in-polygon

I have two spatial objects, one polygon and one points. The polygons may overlap. I would like to associate each point with ALL the polygons it falls in. When the polygons do not overlap, I can do a simple points in polygons, but I am a bit stuck in the case of overlapping polygons. For example:

```
square<-rbind(c(10,10,20,20,15,25,25,15),
              c(15,15,25,25,10,20,20,10))

ID<-c("A","B")

polys<-SpatialPolygons(list(
  Polygons(list(Polygon(matrix(square[1, ], ncol=2, byrow=FALSE))), ID[1]),
  Polygons(list(Polygon(matrix(square[2, ], ncol=2, byrow=FALSE))), ID[2])
))

x<-c(15,17,22,22)
y<-c(22,18,12,22)
data<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4))
# points from scratch
coords = cbind(x, y)
sp = SpatialPoints(coords)
# make spatial data frame
points = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, data)
points = SpatialPointsDataFrame(sp, data)
```

Point 1 is inside Polygon A;
Point 2 is inside Polygon A and B;
Point 3 is inside Polygon B;
Point 4 is inside NO Polygon.

Ideally I would like a data frame like this:

```
ID P1 P2 P3 ...
1  A  NA NA
2  A  B  NA
3  B  NA NA
4  NA NA NA
```

A priory I can't judge how many potential overlapping polygons that each point falls in but I can set a large upper limit and hope that it is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `raster::extract()` function:

```r
library(raster)

e <- extract(polys,points)

names(e) <- c('point','poly')

e
##   point poly
## 1     1    1
## 2     2    1
## 3     2    2
## 4     3    2
## 5     4   NA
```

And you can spread rows with `table()`:

```r
as.matrix(table(e))
##      poly
## point 1 2
##     1 1 0
##     2 1 1
##     3 0 1
##     4 0 0
```